# How do I keep a script running as a systemd service?

Tags: debian, systemd, python, raspbian

I have a Python script with a function I want to execute every X minutes.

```
from threading import Timer

x = 5

def control():
    Timer(x*60, control).start()
    rest_of_the_function()

control()
```

When I run the script in its Python virtual environment from the terminal, there is no problem; when I run it as systemd service, it calls `control()` function just once and then it doesn't do anything else.

If I check the service through `systemctl status myservice` its *Active* field says *active (running)*. There are no errors in the log.

The content of the /lib/systemd/system/myservice.service file is the following.

```
[Unit]
Description=Short description

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myservice
ExecStart=/home/user/myservice/myvenv/bin/python main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Why does it just call `control()` once? Can I fix it?

Comment: You mean this works when you use python in interactive mode? Where do you call `start()` on the `Timer` object? Did you check with `systemctl` that your python program is actually running and it didn't exit?

Comment: Before trying to create a systemd unit, you'll need to edit your program so that it works from the command line without exiting.

Comment: @sebasth I run it from `bash` as `python main.py`. I missed the `start()` here but I have it in my script (edited the post). How can I check if the python program is running? Only check I know is through `journalctl -u myservice` and there is no exit code or anything like that.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I think it does not exit (at least not if I run it as mentioned in the previous comment).

Comment: You can check the status with `systemctl status myservice` and look at the `Active` field.

Comment: @sebasth I do that (as mentioned in the question) and its active status is `active (running)` all the time.

Comment: Systemd can also report `active (exited)` in the *Active* field. Your script is stuck somewhere else. I tested the [similar script](https://pastebin.com/0NRMqq9Y) started with systemd, which works exactly as expected. Without further details what your program is supposed to do, it's more or less impossible to guess why it doesn't work. Overall, this sounds more like a question for SO instead of U&L.

Comment: @sebasth please try to substitute `rest_of_the_function()` with `print('something')`. It demonstrates the issue. If I run for example `/usr/bin/python main.py` from the terminal it does periodically print "something" but that is not the case if I run it as a systemd service as described above (or with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python main.py` instead) it logs just the first "something" and than just runs without doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are probably experiencing a simple buffering problem. If you are looking for messages on stdout, which by default is the journal for systemd units, then you may have to wait a long time for sufficient data to be printed before it gets flushed out.

A simple test for this is to add the `-u` option to python to make the output unbuffered. Remember to do `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing the service unit file.

You can also use `strace` to attach to the running python process. You will presumably find it waiting on a user futex, but after the appropriate time you should see the futex call return, and then entered again.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. I haven't known any means to access the process other than what it logs by `print()`. When I added `flush=True` to the print arguments it works nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @VaNa did you meant that you set `flush=True` in the systemd service unit ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz No. I had print("something") in the Python code and I just changed it to print("something", flush=True).

Comment: Aaah , i have been using logger instead of print so didnt notice

Answer (score 2):

When using `print()` or anything else which writes to a file descriptor (file, pipe, etc), you need to flush the buffers with `flush()` if you need the output right away.

Alternatively for *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* you can use unbuffered mode  using `-u` option for python described in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/python3.1.html#contenttoc3).

Comment: That was the problem! Now I'm sorry for making such a stupid mistake...